# Options to send mass email to external email ids

Tags: process-builder, schedulebatch, singleemailmessage, massemailmessage, mass-email

I am exploring the options to mass email to people outside of the org. I have a custom object - Employees which has custom field - Email address. I would like to send email(email alert) to the email addresses of each employee at say 12 pm on Sept 7th. I have 10,000+ employee records in salesforce.

I was thinking about creating a batch job which can send a mass email. But I see there is daily limit of 1000 to send emails.Is it correct? What are my options here?, is there any safe and secure appexchange app that can support this? or does campaign standard object can be leveraged for this? Appreciate your views.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check out [MassMailer](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005uxj5EAA)?

Comment: Looks like Massmailer works only with leads and contacts. Is that correct?

Comment: Does seem so. I would think there are many other apps out there. You haven't really shared your AppExchange findings.

Comment: if you can trigger a DML event on the Employee every day and the Employee object has a field of type Email, you can send, per day, workflow email alerts = 1,000 * # licenses in your org. [See Limits doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_email_workflow.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Thanks. How to find out my current daily limit. Is the number displayed anywhere from the setup menu?